# jQuery questions that I had problems to understand

Tags: jquery

First:

```
  .closest('.notice')
```

It will take .notice itself or it will take whats nearest the .notice up the dom tree?

`.next('.notice')` - it will grab whats down the dom tree, right?

Another one:

```
$('#celebTree ul').hide().before('<div class="bla"></div>').prev().addClass('handle closed')
```

with the .prev jQuery should select an element before "bla" and apply the class. But it is applying the class to the element that I am inserting with .before method. Why it is like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest('notice')` is the closest parent that matches or the element itself if it matches:

```
<div class="notice"> //This will be selected with $("#target").closest(".notice")
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>

<div class="notice">
    <div id="target" class="notice"></div>  //This will be selected with $("#target").closest(".notice")
</div>
```

`.next('notice')` selects the next element sibling if it matches:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<div class="notice"></div> //This will be selected with $("#target").next(".notice")

<div id="target"></div>  //NOTHING will be selected with $("#target").next(".notice")
<div></div>
```

`.before()` doesn't return a new jQuery object, it returns the old one that you inserted content before to:

```
$('#celebTree ul').hide().before('<div class="bla"></div>') 
//Returns the '#celebTree ul'. NOT jQuery object wrapping '<div class="bla"></div>'
```

Since you just inserted before the element and `prev` operates on `'#celebTree ul'` here, `prev` will take the previous element sibling, which is that content.

Answer (score 0):

```
.closest('.notice')
```

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will traverse the DOM tree (upwards) and return the first ancestor that matches the selector.

```
.next('.notice')
```

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will return the immediately following sibling, *if* it matches the selector.

```
$('#celebTree ul').hide().before('<div class="bla"></div>').prev().addClass('handle closed')
```

This applies the class to the element you are inserting because [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) will return the the same jQuery object it was called on (the inserted element is not added to the matched set). Since the matched element now has your inserted immediately preceding it, [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will return the new element.